# event action from usercontrol not propagating to MainWindow to be handled

Tags: c#, wpf, events, event-bubbling

I have in my user control button in datagrid to which I attached a command.
This command I handle in the ViewModel

```
Private void EditClient(Client client)
{
     EditClientRequest(client.OID);
}

public event Action<int> EditClientRequest = delegate {   };
```

Debugging on click I can see that EditClient is called and parameter is  indeed ID of the client. But in the MainWindowViewModel this event is never handled, it never arrives.

In MainWindowViewModel constructor I call
....

```
 _clientViewModel.EditClientRequest += NavToClient;
```

....

```
private void NatToClient(int clientId)
{
   _clientAddEditViewModel.myClientId = clientId;
   CurrentViewModel = _clientAddEditViewModel;
}
```

Any idea why this might happen?

Thank you in advance for help.

EDIT:

MainWindowViewModel:

```
private ClientViewModel _clientViewModel = new ClientViewModel();
private ClientControlListViewModel _clientControlViewModel = new ClientControlListViewModel();
private BillListViewModel _billViewModel = new BillListViewModel();
private ClientAddEditViewModel _clientAddEditViewModel = new ClientAddEditViewModel();

public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _clientViewModel.EditClientRequest += NavToClient;
        CurrentViewModel = _clientViewModel;
    }

    private void NavToClient(int clientId)
    {
        _clientAddEditViewModel.myClientId = clientId;
        CurrentViewModel = _clientAddEditViewModel;

    }
```

Comment: Initializing an event with a dummy anonymous method only *seems* convenient.  Until you have to debug a "why does the event not get raised?" problem.  Delete it, you'll now know more.

Comment: Thank Hans,  now it is a null... ? what am I missing?

Comment: Now you have a *fact*, you know that the main window isn't actually subscribing the event.  So of course it won't be raised.  If the debugger tells you that the statement executes then you have another fact, _clientViewModel references the wrong object.

Comment: Thank Hans, well this buffles me. As you can see in the constructor (see the EDIT) I am assigning the _clientViewModel.EditClientRequest and then the same _clientViewModel as a currentViewModel. Therefore I do not understand how comes EditClientRequest is null?

Comment: Add breakpoint to the ClientViewModel ctor and ClientViewModel.EditClient. Either the ctor is called more than once or EditClient method is never called, imho.

Comment: Thank you Liero and Hans, you are both right. The contructor for ClientViewModel is for a strange reason called twice, therefor I am clicking on second instance and listening to the first one....  Now I should "just" find out why is this happening....